# UIPasteboard Puzzle

Tags: iphone, uipasteboard

When using the code

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:@"mung"];
NSLog(@"%@", [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string);
```

the console reports the new value of the string, but typing command-V in another application shows the previous pasteboard contents (which may be nothing).

Is there a reliable way to save a single string for use in another application?

Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: Adding the following note: I can place the above code into a project which essentially consists of writing something into the general pasteboard, and does nothing else, and still the data does not appear in the clipboard.  Is it possible it's a setting on my development iMac?

Comment: After much head-banging and hair-pulling, I determined that the issue is my expectation of the test environment.  One cannot actually fully test the above code in the simulator.  The above code writes to the simulator's pasteboard, which is independent of the iMac's pasteboard.

The above code works just fine on the iPhone itself.

Answer (score 2):

The simulator's UIPasteboard (accessed via the menu controller, processed by `pasteboardd`) is independent from the host's NSPasteboard (accessed via Cmd+C/V, processed by `/usr/sbin/pboard`).